# Limit of $ (2^n)\sin(n) $ as $n$ goes to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I'm stuck with the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} (2^n)\sin(n) $. I've been trying the squeeze theorem but it doesn't seem to work. I can't think of a second way to tackle the problem. Any push in the right direction would be much appreciated.

> Also, please don't just post the answer up because I want to try and get it.

Here's what I've got so far:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}  (2^n)\sin(n) $$

So I know, $\ sin(n) $ is bound by -1 and 1, but multiplying the inequality by $\ 2^n $ will give me  a negative and positive $\ 2^n $. So I am stuck here. This would mean that the function is bounded by limits that tend to negative and positive infinity, pretty useless.

So can I take the absolute value of each side of the inequality? Like this:

$$  \lvert-2^n\rvert  \le \lvert 2^n \sin(n) \rvert  \le \lvert 2^n\rvert $$

If this works, I can say it tends to infinity, but it seems a bit dodgy to me.

Thank you for taking a look at this problem.

Comment: Every interval $[n\pi/2-1/2, n\pi/2+1/2]$, $n$ odd contains an integer. Use this to show some subsequence tends to $\infty$ and some subsequence tends to $-\infty$.

Comment: Limit does not exist

Comment: Questions should be be marked as solved by editing the title, but rather by accepting an answer. (Admittedly, David Mitra's comment may be more informative than Graham Kemp's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every interval $[n\pi/2-1/2, n\pi/2+1/2]$, $n$ odd contains an integer. Use this to show some subsequence tends to $\infty$ and some subsequence tends to $-\infty$. -- [David Mitra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894917/limit-of-2n-sinn-as-n-goes-to-infinity#comment1847157_894917)

Answer (score 0):

No.   You cannot take the absolute value when you are looking for the limit.   It's not a valid concept.

$2^n\sin n$ oscillates periodically between $-2^n$ and $+2^n$ as $n$ tends to infinitude.   It does not converge on a limit.   It does not even tend towards infinitude.   No limit exists.